# kinect.launch for TurtleBot Not Working

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I type "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch" in order to start my kinect for map building, I get these messages published over and over again. What do you think is the problem?

```
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e2478f74-dbe6-11e0-9949-78e40017343c/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [1195]
[ERROR] [1315697291.135056085]: Cannot load nodelet /kinect_laser_narrow for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1315697291.135299970]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.135376516]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.135439793]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[openni_camera-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e2478f74-dbe6-11e0-9949-78e40017343c/openni_camera-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_camera-3] restarting process
process[openni_camera-3]: started with pid [1220]
[ERROR] [1315697291.238780728]: Cannot load nodelet /openni_camera for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1315697291.239030480]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.239132867]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.239187762]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ERROR] [1315697291.359337041]: Cannot load nodelet /kinect_laser for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1315697291.359575688]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.359654260]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.359711250]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ERROR] [1315697291.365831437]: Cannot load nodelet /pointcloud_throttle for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1315697291.366078955]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.366150682]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.366197964]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ERROR] [1315697291.538221534]: Cannot load nodelet /kinect_laser_narrow for one exists with that name already
[ WARN] [1315697291.538465490]: Publisher on '/openni_manager/bond' destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.538549998]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
[ WARN] [1315697291.538598189]: WallTimer destroyed immediately after creation.  Did you forget to store the handle?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11166/kinect.launch-for-turtlebot-not-working/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem is in the error:

```
Cannot load nodelet /openni_camera for one exists with that name already
```

This suggests that openni_camera has already been launched.  When you launch the map building demo it already starts the kinect for you, you should not start it seperately.  If you're still having trouble please post all the things which you have launched and we can look for the conflict.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-12**:
I am launching it in the turtlebot

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-11**:
it seems like the camera isn't coming up are you launching kinect.launch on the turtlebot or the desktop?

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-10**:
I just went through the tutorial, but no images are displayed when I select the camera or point cloud data.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-10**:
@ParkerGibbons did you have a chance to look at this tutorial it might help you http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-10**:
"ssh -X turtlebot@192.168.1.11" "export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311" "rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard&" "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch" Then I open rviz in a seperate terminal, because I am just trying to see data from the kinect right now, not make a map.

**Comment by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on 2011-09-10**:
Even if I do not launch the demo, I still get the same error. Here is what I do :